# PyCharm - Debugging freezes when using pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, debugging, pycharm

When I am using the debugger everything works fine and fast, except when using a pandas or numpy object, even for very small data sets. After typing the name of the object, when I type "." to use any method or atribute, pycharm freezes for about 40 seconds.

I've tried upgrading everything to the latest version. I've tried changing the settings of the debugger, all without success.

Why is this happening only to the pandas and numpy? Any suggestions on what should I do?

## EDIT

What worked for me was to disable IPython. In **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console**, I unchecked the **Use IPython if available** option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest [PyCharm 2018.2 EAP build](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) introduces "on-demand" variable loading policy. I believe it should fix your problem: [PY-29468](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29468).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. The problem persists, even for small dataframes. I am testing this with a DataFrame with 6 data points.

Comment: I see. Do you use IPython? There's a different problem with it [PY-30285](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30285). Unfortunately, the fix is not yet included in the public builds. One can disable **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Show console variables by default** option as a workaround.

Comment: That is the exact problem that I am having. I've tried disabling the "show console variables by default" but also without success. But when I disable the "Use IPython if available" then the debug window changes from `In[x]` to `>>>>`. At least it is not slow anymore. Is there a downside to not using the IPython environment in the debugger?

Comment: Oh that's fine. Thanks for the Help @Pavel Karateev.

Comment: I just run into this problem after upgrading docker and Catalina. But this solution didn't work for me.